# Sorting not working on next page of pagination PHP BS-4

Tags: php, sorting, pagination

I already created a table that has limit and it is working well with pagination

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])){
$currentPage = $_GET['page'];
}else{
$currentPage = 1;
}
$startFrom = ($currentPage * $showRecordPerPage) - $showRecordPerPage;
$totalEmpSQL = "SELECT * FROM producttable";
$allEmpResult = mysqli_query($conn, $totalEmpSQL);
$totalProducts = mysqli_num_rows($allEmpResult);
$lastPage = ceil($totalProducts/$showRecordPerPage);

$firstPage = 1;
 $prev = $currentPage - 1;
 $next = $currentPage + 1;

$sortertype = "name";
$sorterorder = "ASC";
$sort = "";
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
  $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}

if ($sort == 'nameasc') { // If you Sort it with value of your  select options
$sortertype = "name";
$sorterorder = "ASC";

} elseif ($sort == 'namedesc') { // else if you do not pass any value from select option will return this
$sortertype = "name";
$sorterorder = "DESC";
}

$empSQL = "SELECT id,name, price,description
FROM `producttable`  ORDER BY $sortertype $sorterorder LIMIT $startFrom, $showRecordPerPage";
$empResult = mysqli_query($conn, $empSQL);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empResult)) {}

**for pagination 

<ul class="pagination justify-content-start" >
               <li class="page-item <?php if($currentPage <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
                   <a class="page-link"
                       href="<?php if($currentPage <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?page=" . $prev; } ?>">Prev</a>
               </li>

               <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $lastPage; $i++ ): ?>
               <li class="page-item <?php if($currentPage == $i) {echo 'active'; } ?>">
                   <a class="page-link" href="inde.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"> <?= $i; ?> </a>
                   
               </li>
               <?php endfor; ?>

               <li class="page-item <?php if($currentPage >= $lastPage) { echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
                   <a class="page-link"
                       href="<?php if($currentPage >= $lastPage){ echo '#'; } else {echo "?page=". $next; } ?>">Next</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
```

**and also manage to create a working sorting options that displays the type of order and doesnt reset when changed

```
<select name="sort" id="myselect" onchange="sort(this.value);" class="py-1" >


         <option value="nameasc"  <?php if($sort == 'nameasc'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Name:Asc</option>
     <option value="namedesc"  <?php if($sort == 'namedesc'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Name:Desc</option>
</select> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  function sort(option){

   window.location = window.location.pathname+'?sort='+option;
}
</script>
```

the only problem is that when the page goes to the next page, the sorting options resets and also the table reset to default sorting. Is there anyway to make the pagination connect to the sorting options part?

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the GET value received for the `sort`

`$sort = $_GET['sort'];`

So your code should be

```php
$sort = $_GET['sort']; // this line is missing

if ($sort == 'nameasc') { // If you Sort it with value of your  select options
$sortertype = "name";
$sorterorder = "ASC";

} elseif ($sort == 'namedesc') { // else if you do not pass any value from select option will return this
$sortertype = "name";
$sorterorder = "DESC";
}
```

Comment: oh, i forgot to add it to my post, sorry . i edited it now. I already have that line but it seems like the problem is from the pagination code that refreshes the whole php file when clicked the next page and not retaining the changes from first page